# Does interprocess communication via binder happens with shared memory approach?

Tags: android, ipc, shared-memory, android-binder

Today I'm really surprised to see this. I've two apps and both has the similar line,

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
Log.i(TAG, "The value of power manager service from app one is : " + pm.toString());
```

and in another,

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
Log.i(TAG, "The value of power manager service from app two is : " + pm.toString());
```

To my surprise both are printing the result something like this,

```
The value of power manager service from app one is : android.os.PowerManager@cd04e
The value of power manager service from app two is : android.os.PowerManager@cd04e
```

The whole day I wandered around the internet to know how this is happening? As far I understood they are binder used for communicating with the system process under which all android services would run.

But I expected two different instances of binder to get generated since they both are different process. This result is surprising me since it's printing the same value. If this is the case do binder really allocate memory in shared memory?

With googling, i found something called mmap with which multiple apps can share the memory? Does binder internally uses this?

Is this a security threat when multiple processes sharing the same instance? Who creates this instance and how this is shared between the process? I'm super curious to know this. Breaking my head in trying to understand this.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood : Your thoughts on this please. I read your article here where you have mentioned the same (https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/binders-death-recipients.html). How is this happening?

Comment: @CommsWare : Do you have any idea on this?